# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10

Tags: wireless, adapter

I've recently gotten into Ubuntu (dual booting with windows 10) a few months ago, but I've had this reoccurring issue where I will boot into Ubuntu and there will be "no wi-fi adapter found" in my gnome. First, I was using Ubuntu 20.04, then this week I upgraded to 20.10. With both OS versions, this issue did not happen after the first 30 or so reboots. Then, it started happening. The only way to resolve this issue on 20.04 was to unplug my computer, then plug it in. Perhaps there are capacitors that remain charged after rebooting..... I built my own PC and here are the specs. I recently did a new build for 20.10, so I will list the components I used for 20.04 first:

CPU: AMD 3700x
RAM: Corsair 16x2
GPU: GTX 970 from EVGA
PS: was Corsair Cx550M, now is EVGA Supernova 650GM
MB: was MSI MPG x570 Gaming Pro Carbon Wifi, now is Aorus B550i Aorus Pro Ax

Seperate MB, separate wifi chips, same issue. Sounds like an issue with the OS. Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions to fix this issue?

```
maxwell@maxwell-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for maxwell: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc300000-fc30ffff memory:fc310000-fc313fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc200000-fc203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 22:f3:cf:24:0b:1c
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.47 link=yes multicast=yes
maxwell@maxwell-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 248a:8367 Maxxter Telink Wireless Receiver
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05a3:9331 ARC International Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 048d:5702 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2a70:f00e OnePlus Technology (Shenzhen) Co., Ltd. HD1905
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
maxwell@maxwell-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation E16 PCIe4 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ee
02:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43eb
02:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43e9
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
03:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
03:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
03:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation E12 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] (rev a1)
08:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
09:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
0a:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
0a:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
0a:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
0a:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
maxwell@maxwell-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Wi-Fi issues are generally hardware specific.  You should determine what is the make/model of your adapter and check with the manufacturer for a driver. You can also use the make/model as search terms to see if someone else has encountered and solved this issue.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like it might be an issue with the dual-boot. I restarted without booting into windows and there was no wifi issue. There are some people suggesting disable safe booting in windows to resolve this issue.

Comment: disable Windows Fast Startup feature.